# How can I get unique record from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have a collection named 'myplace'. It has the following fields: place_name, latitude, longitude, city, country.

I want all the cities that start with the letter "A". I tried the following:

```
type Place struct{
    City string `bson: "City"`
}
```

For retrieving the result from the db:

```
var city_name []Place
err = coll.Find(bson.M{"city": bson.M{"$regex":"^a", "$options":"si"}}).All(&city_name)
```

It's getting all the results. The problem is that some of the 'myplace' documents have the same city, so it's returning duplicate city names.

Let's say I have 5 myplaces, 3 with the city name "Baton Rouge" and remaining having "Trivandrum, Kochi". When I try to get the city starting with "B", it's returning "Baton Rouge" 3 times.

How can I ensure each city_name is unique?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And then what? Clearly "city_name" is duplicated throughout your data for the conditions specified. What do you intend to do with the other fields in the document? Do you want the first? Do you want the last? Do you want some things by "min/max" value? If you want a real answer to your question you need to ask a **better** question that states what you actually intend to do.

Comment: @NeilLunn Lets say I have 5 places, in this 3 having city name Baton Rouge and remaining having Trivandrum, Kochi like this. Now am trying to get the city which having starting letter "B", its returning 3 times times "Baton Rouge"

Comment: It's still basically a bit broad. Doing a regex query like "^B" would return anything starting with "B". You can always break this down to "distinct" values of a field ( which there is functionality for ) but what I have said is this possibly masks the intent. "Baton Rougue" might have "zipcode" fields elsewhere and you don't say what you really intend to do. "Distinct" is a relative term to your intent. I'm asking you to "state your intent". It's as basic data principle, not specific to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Distinct method, in the shell it will look like :

```
db.foo.distinct( "city",  { "city" : { "$regex" : /^A/i    } }  );
```

In Go:

```
 var result []string 

 err = c.Find( bson.M{"city": bson.M{"$regex":"^a","$options":"si"}}  ).Distinct("city", &result) 

 if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) 
 }

 fmt.Println( result )
```

Comment: Am using like this type Place struct{City         string   `bson: "City"`}  var result []Place

 err = c.Find( bson.M{"city": bson.M{"$regex":"^a","$options":"si"}}  ).Distinct("city", &result) 

 if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) 
 }

 fmt.Println( result ) Its returning empty

Comment: The distinct operator will select each value of a the attribute "city", so the result is an array of the type of city field, not an array of Place.  You need to be sure you are using *var result []string*

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Distinct](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Distinct):

```
err = coll.Find(bson.M{"city": bson.M{"$regex":"^a", "$options":"si"}}).Distinct("city", &city_name)
```

..this assumes that `city_name` is actually a slice.

Comment: Sorry its returning empty array

Comment: Update your question to include what you tried - also include more detail like your document structure and the declaration of `city_name`. When you do that I will remove my answer (so I know you've updated it).

Comment: PS: This works in my test. It also works when I manually throw `db.cities.distinct("name", { name: { "$regex": "^[^a]" } })` at my test collection.